# MySQL: Pick which row when values are the same

Tags: mysql

Ok so I'm working on a larger SQL statement, but I've come across an issue that I cant seem to find a fix for elsewhere. If I simplify what I currently have, take a table like:

```
    col_1     |     col_2     |      col_3
     100      |    default    |      Hello
     500      |    default    |      World
     500      |    override   |      Other
```

I want to select all rows that have unique values from col_1, but when I run into duplicates I need to use col_2 to determine which of the duplicates to use.

So if I selected col_3 values from above I would get 'Hello' and 'Other'.

I know DISTINCT wont get me what I want and I've tried some grouping and ordering methods, but because the grouping is calculated first, it doesnt seem to be the answer.

Comment: you dont want duplicates in col_2 or col_1?? Would you also accept row 1 and row 2 as a return result for your query?

Comment: I dont want duplicates in col_1 or col_2, however the critical part is that I need to define that 'override' in col_2 takes precedence over 'default'. So row 1 and 2 would not be acceptable only row 1 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `ORDER BY` in a subquery and then `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT * FROM 
       (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY col_1 DESC) 
GROUP BY col_2
```